# When should the subjunctive be used after "mientras"?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, adverbios, indicativa, tiempos-verbales

When should *mientras* or *mientras que* be followed by the subjunctive and when by the indicative? In both cases, how is *mientras* usually translated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Subtle...

> Mientras llueve, escucho música.       (*llueve*: indicative)
>
> *While it rains, I listen to music*
>
> Mientras llueva, me quedaré en casa.   (*llueva*: subjunctive )
>
> *As long as it rains, I'll stay at home.*

*"Mientras + indicative"* implies mere **simultaneity** (at the same time something happens, another thing takes place).

*"Mientras + subjunctive"* suggests a **condition** (as long as something is happening ...)